# add dependencies to a library, and add them to a binary which depends on that library

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

### What I have:

I have a non-recursive makefile which searches for `module.mk` files, and includes them

```
modules := $(shell find . -name module.mk)
include $(modules)
```

If I want to create a **static library**, the `module.mk` looks like this:

```
$(eval $(call make-lib, test_lib))
```

Which will find a list of all `.cpp` files in the current directory, and call `do-make-lib`, with:

- `$1` being the library name
- `$2` being the list of source files

`do-make-lib` is defined as follows (some details omitted for brevity):

```
define do-make-lib
    $(addprefix $(addprefix $(LIB_DIR)lib,$1),.a): $(call src_to_obj, $2)
    @$(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $$@ $$?
endef
```

Now when I build a **binary**, `module.mk` looks like this:

```
$(eval $(call make-bin, test_bin, test_lib))
```

Similarly, `make-bin` will find a list of all `.cpp` files in the current directory, and call `do-make-bin`, with:

- `$1` being the binary name
- `$2` being the list of source files
- `$3` being the list of static libraries to link against

`do-make-bin` is defined as follows:

```
define do-make-bin
    $(addprefix $(BIN_DIR),$1): $(call src_to_obj,$2) \
        $(addsuffix .a,$(addprefix $(LIB_DIR)lib,$3))))
    @$(CXX) $(call src_to_obj,$2) \
        -L/usr/lib -L$(LIB_DIR) \
        -Wl$(,)-Bstatic $(addprefix -l,$3) \
        -o $$@
endef
```

### My problem:

Libraries depend on other libraries. When I link the binary, I need to give is a list of **all** the libraries it depends on, in the correct order.

```
$(eval $(call make-bin, my_bin, lib5 lib4 lib3 lib2 lib1))
```

### What I want:

I would like to pass an additional parameter to `make-lib` which is a list of **dependencies**

```
$(eval $(call make-lib, test_lib, lib3 lib2 lib1))
```

In `do-make-lib` I could then make a variable which includes the name of the library being built, which captures the dependencies

*pseudo code (not sure of syntax - how do I build a variable from another variable?)*

```
$1_DEPS = $3
```

Then when building my binary I can include the libs' dependencies as dependencies of the binary, and also add them to the link line

*pseudo code (not sure of syntax)*

```
define do-make-bin

    # build a list of dependencies, eg: lib2_DEPS lib2_DEPS lib1_DEPS
    $1_DEPS = $(addsuffix _DEPS,$3)

    $(addprefix $(BIN_DIR),$1): $(call src_to_obj,$2) \
        $(addsuffix .a,$(addprefix $(LIB_DIR)lib,$3)) \
        $(addsuffix .a,$(addprefix $(LIB_DIR)lib,$($1_DEPS))))) # include the libs dependencies as dependencies of the binary
    @$(CXX) $(call src_to_obj,$2) \
        -L/usr/lib -L$(LIB_DIR) \
        -Wl$(,)-Bstatic $(addprefix -l,$3) $(addprefix -l,$($1_DEPS))) \ # link against dependencies' dependencies
        -o $$@
endef
```

### Questions:

- Is this feasible?
- Can someone help me with the syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have these definitions (say)

```
test_lib_DEPS := lib5 lib4 lib3 lib2 lib1
lib5_DEPS := lib6 lib3
lib6_DEPS := lib1
lib2_DEPS := lib1
```

Expanding `test_lib_DEPS` by hand, we find we first want `lib5`, followed by the recursive expansion of `$lib5_DEPS`, then `lib4` and `$lib4_DEPS` etc. A depth-first expansion.

```
expand = $(foreach _,$1,$_ $(call expand,${$__DEPS}))

$(error [$(call expand,${test_lib_DEPS})])
```

This gives

```
$ make
1:9: *** [lib5 lib6 lib1  lib3  lib4  lib3  lib2 lib1  lib1 ].  Stop.
```

Pretty good. You may wish to tease out those duplicates. `$(sort)` fits the bill, but when linking you probably want to preserve ordering. Following similar arguments we can write a `uniq` function in functional style: return the first element of the arguments, followed by a recursive call of `uniq`, but with the first element missing since we already have it.

```
test_lib_DEPS := lib5 lib4 lib3 lib2 lib1
lib5_DEPS := lib6 lib3
lib6_DEPS := lib1
lib2_DEPS := lib1

uniq = $(if $1,$(firstword $1) $(call uniq,$(filter-out $(firstword $1),$1)))
depth-first = $(foreach _,$1,$_ $(call depth-first,${$__DEPS}))
expand = $(call uniq,$(call depth-first,$1))

$(error [$(call expand,${test_lib_DEPS})])
```

Giving

```
$ make
1:10: *** [lib5 lib6 lib1 lib3 lib4 lib2 ].  Stop.
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! I have an issue where I list a circular dependency. I have asked a [related question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30837891/makefile-library-dependencies-resolve-circular-dependency). Do you have any input please?